# How to study temperature influence on Li-Ion Batteries?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, simulation, matlab

I would like to study and simulate the influence of the ambient temperature on a given Lithium Ion  Cell. Behavior while charging or discharging for both internal Resistance and capacity.
My Battery-Model is based on [this paper](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOoJ-xuqjJAhWBXBoKHcmHAJAQFggrMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.evs24.org%2Fwevajournal%2Fphp%2Fdownload.php%3Ff%3Dvol3%2FWEVJ3-2230080.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFwP1YfE3leIvF7_uwxekOGsFt7Cw&bvm=bv.108194040,d.d24) (see also [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/battery.html)).

The information from the Battery i want to simulate are data sheets with

Power curves (Power-SoC) for 5[s] and 30[s] for different Temperatures.

And I-V Plots for different (SoC's) for 5[s] and 30[s]. (See below)

[image]

[image]

One thing that confuses me are these measurements of 5 and 30 [s], does it refer to the time difference between each measurement?

As it's my first encounter with Batteries i'm a bit confused, so how could I use these data sheets with my model?

Comment: What data sheets?

Comment: @Andyaka data sheets provided by the producer of the battery cells!

Comment: Simulate with what, like in hardware so you can power something without having the battery or in software? I also wonder what a power curve for a battery might look like (is it the maximum power which the battery can deliver or something else?) can you share an example?

Comment: @Arsenal simulate with SW (octave/dymola) as it's for a feasibility test/study, so no HW should be tested

Comment: Have you done any prior research on this? If I google "Lithium battery simulator" I get lots and lots of results from hardware to software and from [general](http://www.mathworks.com/tagteam/71900_IEEE%202012%20High%20Fidelity%20Lithium%20Battery%20Model%20with%20Thermal%20Effect.pdf) to [chemistry-specific](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098135411001785) and even in [low earth orbit](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.553.2150&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Btw, a highly-cited paper (~1000 citations) is http://users.ece.gatech.edu/rincon-mora/publicat/jrnls/tec05_batt_mdl.pdf so I'd assume a lot of people use that; seems pretty simple too.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff yes i found myself a few papers and even implemented one, but i still don't get how to use these data for my given model, as my Knowledge about electical engineering was limited in the basics (Ohm's law, Kirchhoff's law, ...)